# Is there any way to align this circle?

Tags: modeling

I would like to align a circle with the edge under it. But every time I try to rotate it around the z-axis, it never gets perfectly aligned and overall this "window" has some curves in it.

I want it to be rotated the same way as the edges around it as if they were the same plane.

[image: Here i am trying to rotate but manually there will be always some small error]

Comment: this selected edges are the circle and i want to align it with this edge above it

Comment: Some images are missing.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:
click on the edge you to to align, in order so 3d cursor will be there-->add a plane and scale it a bit--> select the object you want to move--> enable snap during transform (small magnet icon) and select snap to face--> press G to grab and X,Y ou Z to move on that axis. Once it is close to the plane, will snap onto it. press enter, deactivate the magnet and delect the plane